# Showing a confirmation message after ajax request

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I want to show a message like `your action has been done` to users after submit a form.

Here is what i did : 
dispatch an action `ADD_COUNTRY_SUCCESS` if response was successfull and make `addCountryStatus` true and in component in the `componentDidUpdate` i will check the value but this will only work once and after that it will be true forever.

**component :**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Button, Checkbox, message } from 'antd';


class AddCountry extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidUpdate(){
    const {addCountryStatus} = this.props.country;
    if(addCountryStatus != undefined){
      if(addCountryStatus){
        message.success('عملیات با موفقیت انجام شد.');
      }else{
        message.error('خطا در انجام عملیات');
      }
    }else{
    }
  }
  state = {
    isForeign: false,
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        var self = this;
        self.props.addCountry(values);
        this.props.form.resetFields();
      }
    });
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      isForeign: !this.state.isForeign
    });

  };

  render() {

    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;

    return (
      <div className="animated fadeIn">
        <Row className="justify-content-center">
          <Col xs="6" md="6">
            <Card>
              <CardHeader>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <Form.Item>
                    {getFieldDecorator('name', {
                      rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Required.' }],
                    })(
                      <Input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Country"
                      />,
                    )}
                  </Form.Item>
                  <Form.Item>
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                      Submit
                    </Button>
                  </Form.Item>
                </Form>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



export default Form.create()(AddCountry);
```

**Saga**

```
function addCountryRequest(action) {
    return axios
    .post( API + '/country',
      action,
      config
    )
      .then(response => response)
      .catch(error => ({ error }));
}

function* addCountry(action) {

  try {

    const countryResponse = yield call(addCountryRequest, action.payload);
    console.log(countryResponse)
    yield put({type: "ADD_COUNTRY_SUCCESS", countryResponse});
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message)
    yield put({type: "ADD_COUNTRY_FAILED", message: e.message});
  }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
const country = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_COUNTRY:
      return {
        ...state,
        country: action.payload.name,
        isForeign: action.payload.isForeign,
      }
    case ADD_COUNTRY_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        addCountryStatus: true,
      }
    case ADD_COUNTRY_FAILED:
      console.log(action)
      return {
        ...state,
        addCountryStatus: false,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Actually i want to show a message to user whenever there is a response from server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also add `addCountryStatus: false,` when you dispatch `ADD_COUNTRY` (at the start of the request).

I would also suggest a few more things: 
1) Add a loading status. `ADD_COUNTRY` should only set `loading: true, error: false`. Then upon dispatching `ADD_COUNTRY_SUCCESS`, set `loading` to false, and update the state with `countryResponse`. That way you won't get inconsistencies with the api and the app. For example, what if you added a new country to the state, but it wasn't added to the server, because of an error. Also `ADD_COUNTRY_FAILED` sets `loading` to `false` and `error` to `true`.

2) `componentDidUpdate` accepts previous props as an argument. That way you can surely check if `addCountryStatus` has changed specifically from `false` to `true`:

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    const {addCountryStatus, error} = this.props.country;
    if(!prevProps.country.addCountryStatus && addCountryStatus){
      message.success('عملیات با موفقیت انجام شد.');
      return;
    }
    if(!prevProps.country.error && error) {
      message.error('خطا در انجام عملیات');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and idea, but there is a problem that `componentDidUpdate` is getting called every time I write into textfield !!!

Comment: replace `!prevProps.addCountryStatus` with `!prevProps.country.addCountryStatus` and it's fixed

Answer (score 3):

Maybe after getting the message you can dispatch an action to update addCountryStatus to false inside the reducer but that's not optimal.

A better solution would be to  make a component that show success and error message which is connected to a new reducer containing an array of requests status.

In your saga instead of dispatching ADD_COUNTRY_SUCCESS you can call something like ADD_REQUEST_STATUS and passing the type (for this case -> country) and the status. then inside your new messageComponent you show the right message depending on status and type. Then when the user dismiss the message or when the message disappear then you can dispatch something like DELETE_REQUEST_STATUS.